# bash script for man with custom output

Tags: bash, manpage

I'm trying to do a bash script which gives me only the first line of man for "n" commands.

example:

```
$ sh ./start.sh ls wazup top 
ls - list directory contents
wazup - manpage does not exist
top - display Linux tasks
```

This is my current code:

```
! bin/bash/
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
which $1> /dev/null
man $1 | head -6 | tail -1
if [ $? = 0  ]
then
echo "manpage does not exist"
fi
shift
done
```

My Output is:

```
ls - list directory contents
manpage does not exist
No manual entry for wazzup
manpage does not exist
top - display Linux processes
manpage does not exist
```

Comment: An exit status of 0 represents success (the opposite of the C-style boolean convention). Non-zero values indicate failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the status code returned by `man`, not once it's piped through `head` and `tail` (which will be wrong as it will be the return status of `tail`).

Answer (score 1):

Many Thanks Alex!

Solved it by not using pipes with your help! :)

Here's my final code for anyone that needs it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
which $1> /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
man -f $1
else 
echo "$1: manpage does not exist" 
fi
shift
done
```